# What's wrong with my table?

Tags: tables, arrays

I am trying to write the following entries in a table

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
$\begin{array}
\toprule
k & \lbrace c_{kj} : j=1, \cdots , 8 \rbrace  \\[1ex]
1 &  \lbrace 0 , 190 , 359 , 514 , 676 , 810 , 931 , 1013 \rbrace  \\
2 &  \lbrace 190 ,   0 , 178 , 333 , 496 , 630 , 750 , 831 \rbrace  \\
3 &  \lbrace 359, 178 ,   0 , 156 , 318 , 452 , 573 , 655 \rbrace  \\
4 & \lbrace 514 , 333 , 156 ,   0 , 246 , 297 , 417 , 499  \rbrace \\
5 &  \lbrace 676 , 496 , 318 , 246 ,   0 , 156 , 255 , 338   \rbrace \\
6 & \lbrace 810 , 630 , 452 , 297 , 156 ,   0 , 120 , 204 \rbrace  \\
7 &  \lbrace 931 , 750 , 573 , 417 , 255 , 120 ,   0  , 85  \rbrace \\
8 & \lbrace 1013 , 831 , 655 , 499 , 338 , 204 ,  85 ,   0 \rbrace   \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption {$ \lbrace c_{kj} : j=1, \cdots , 8 \rbrace $ for $ k=1, \cdot 8$}
\end{table}
```

I get several errors the first of which is " Package array error"

Can anyone advise as to how to fix this ?
Thanks!

Comment: The `array` environment needs a preamble of specified columns just like standard `tabular` needs: Try `$\begin{array}{cc}`.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax error (missing argument for environment `array`) is already explained in comment and answer. Thus this answer makes the example complete and adds full alignment for all coefficients in the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    $\begin{array}{
        c
        >{\lbrace\hfill}r@{$, $}
        *{6}{r@{$, $}}
        r<{\rbrace}
      }
      \toprule
      k & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\lbrace c_{kj}\colon j=1, \dots , 8 \rbrace} \\
      \midrule
      1 &  0   & 190 & 359 & 514 & 676 & 810 & 931 & 1013 \\
      2 &  190 &   0 & 178 & 333 & 496 & 630 & 750 &  831 \\
      3 &  359 & 178 &   0 & 156 & 318 & 452 & 573 &  655 \\
      4 &  514 & 333 & 156 &   0 & 246 & 297 & 417 &  499 \\
      5 &  676 & 496 & 318 & 246 &   0 & 156 & 255 &  338 \\
      6 &  810 & 630 & 452 & 297 & 156 &   0 & 120 &  204 \\
      7 &  931 & 750 & 573 & 417 & 255 & 120 &   0 &   85 \\
      8 & 1013 & 831 & 655 & 499 & 338 & 204 &  85 &    0 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{array}$
    \caption {$ \lbrace c_{kj}\colon j=1, \dots , 8 \rbrace $ for $ k=1, \dots ,
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The dots of the ellipsis should be on the baseline here, see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239546/whats-wrong-with-my-table/239588#comment569000_239554) of LaRiFaRi.
- The colon is a simple punctuation character here instead of a relational math operator. `\colon` is the punctuation character and `:` the relational math operator.
- Package `array` is used to add the curly braces automatically.
- The second column uses a trick: `>{\lbrace\hfill}r` puts the brace to the left, whereas the cell content is moved to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the column specifiers, possibly

```
\begin{array}{cl}
```

However, this approach doesn't fully consider the fact that you have an array of numbers, and it will be quite difficult to find the values of *c<sub>kj</sub>* from the table.

So I suggest another approach, with the help of `siunitx` and its powerful features for numeric data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c *{8}{S[table-format=4.0]} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{9}{c}{Values of $c_{kj}$} \\
\midrule
\makebox[2em]{$k$} &
  {$j=1$} & {$j=2$} & {$j=3$} & {$j=4$} & {$j=5$} & {$j=6$} & {$j=7$} & {$j=8$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-9}
1 &  0   & 190 & 359 & 514 & 676 & 810 & 931 & 1013 \\
2 &  190 &   0 & 178 & 333 & 496 & 630 & 750 &  831 \\
3 &  359 & 178 &   0 & 156 & 318 & 452 & 573 &  655 \\
4 &  514 & 333 & 156 &   0 & 246 & 297 & 417 &  499 \\
5 &  676 & 496 & 318 & 246 &   0 & 156 & 255 &  338 \\
6 &  810 & 630 & 452 & 297 & 156 &   0 & 120 &  204 \\
7 &  931 & 750 & 573 & 417 & 255 & 120 &   0 &   85 \\
8 & 1013 & 831 & 655 & 499 & 338 & 204 &  85 &    0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption {$\{c_{kj} : j=1,\dots,8\}$ for $k=1,\dots,8$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\begin{table}[h]` is not recommended, it should also include at least `p`, but `htp` is probably better. With `[h]` a `t` specifier would be added anyway.

Note that dots should be low when between commas; but it's even better to load `amsmath` so that `\dots` will be generally able to decide what kind of dots to use, when between two symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Gessler pointed out.  Here is the updated version

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
$\begin{array}{cc}\hline
k & \lbrace c_{kj} : j=1, \cdots , 8 \rbrace  \\[1ex]
1 &  \lbrace 0 , 190 , 359 , 514 , 676 , 810 , 931 , 1013 \rbrace  \\
2 &  \lbrace 190 ,   0 , 178 , 333 , 496 , 630 , 750 , 831 \rbrace  \\
3 &  \lbrace 359, 178 ,   0 , 156 , 318 , 452 , 573 , 655 \rbrace  \\
4 & \lbrace 514 , 333 , 156 ,   0 , 246 , 297 , 417 , 499  \rbrace \\
5 &  \lbrace 676 , 496 , 318 , 246 ,   0 , 156 , 255 , 338   \rbrace \\
6 & \lbrace 810 , 630 , 452 , 297 , 156 ,   0 , 120 , 204 \rbrace  \\
7 &  \lbrace 931 , 750 , 573 , 417 , 255 , 120 ,   0  , 85  \rbrace \\
8 & \lbrace 1013 , 831 , 655 , 499 , 338 , 204 ,  85 ,   0 \rbrace   \\
\hline
\end{array}$
\caption {$ \lbrace c_{kj} : j=1, \cdots , 8 \rbrace $ for $ k=1, \cdot 8$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? R. maybe add a full MWE with `booktabs`, replace `cdots` and `cdot` by `\dots` and use `{rl}` instead of `{cc}`. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I am the downvoter; sorry, it was late and I did not make a comment. I downvoted because this is a regression from the original code (missing `booktabs`) and because it's my solution from the comments (should be CW then) except the entire explanation has been removed (I prefer to try to teach rather than just providing a dump of the corrected code).

Comment: @PaulGessler No rule requires that an answer similar to a previous comment be CW. However, I agree that removing `booktabs` command is a regression from the original code and that instead of pointing to the comment, the error should be explained in the answer.

Comment: @egreg I didn't say it was a rule, but that it was a factor in my decision to downvote. It's common practice to allow the commenter to provide an answer. Indeed, while this answer was being posted I was searching for a duplicate.